# How to set all the elements of array to 0, after initialization or 2nd time in a loop?

Tags: c, arrays

I am stuck with basics of an array. I googled it, but I could not able to solve this. This question  is concept oriented, but I am not able to bridge a gap. Please help me out resolve this.

I am very clear on initializing array for the first time, but not able to clear the array for next time :-( :-(

```
int myArray[10] = { 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5 }; // All elements of myArray are 5
int myArray[10] = { 0 };    // Will initialize all elements to 0
int myArray[10] = { 5 };    // Will initialize myArray[0] to 5 and other elements to 0
static int myArray[10]; // Will initialize all elements to 0

int myArray[10];// This will declare and define (allocate memory) but won’t initialize
int i;  // Loop variable
for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) // Using for loop we are initializing
{
    myArray[i] = 5;
}
```

**Problem statement:**

I am using a Global array which is of size 10000. I have 1k iteration loop, where I have to set the array to 'Zero' or predefined value i.e., 5 for each iteration.

I am doing this at the end of interaction like this:

```
myArray[10000] = { 0 };
```

Its giving error while compiling in GCC compiler.

```
error: [11707] syntax error before '{' token
```

Please help me out resolve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't `memset()` for you? ... `memset()` won't able to set each values to 5.

Comment: memset, loop with incementing index or pointer, bzero... .  maybe you should just move to a different course?

Comment: @ Martin, I can't use Memset, because od some constraint. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: I really don't understand, y this down votes. Is anyone can explain?

Comment: If you're re-initializing your array on each iteration, you may as well *declare* the array inside the loop.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth example code snippets are highly appeciated. please could type in answer?

Comment: Are you Jon Skeet?

Comment: No. I am not Jon Skeet

Comment: how do you decide when `myArray` will be initialized with 0s?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
myArray[10000] = { 0 };
```

is an assignment, not a declaration, so it won't work. You should loop.

```
int myArray[10000] = { 0 };

for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 10000; j++) {
        myArray[j] = ;  // put your value here.
    }
}
```

I am unsure of the purpose of this. Benchmarking?

Answer (score 0):

The trivial implementation of `memset`, without any optimization, is a loop that set each position of an array to a desired value. The problem is memset do this for each **byte**, and it is not what you want. I recommend you to implement an alternative to memset:

```
int *mymemset (int *s, int v, size_t n) {
    unsigned int *p = s;
    while(n--) {
        *p++ = (unsigned int)v;
    }

    return s;
}
```

And use it to initialize your array.

Comment: But my array is of global scope(mentioned in question), not an auto/ local scope. I am using array for many other data manipulation.

Comment: oh.. ok. So you have a global array that you want to initialize with 0s or whatever 1k times? Isn't this a design problem?

Comment: Yes, but I have to strongly go with this option, because of data processing in multiple parts of the code.

Comment: Thanks alot!!, But not able to upvote, because I have less than 15 reputation. Btw I have to call mymemset (myArray, 0, 10000); Is n't it?

Comment: Yes. Or `mymemset(myArray, 5, 10000);`. Try and see if this solves your problem. If it does, accept as an answer. Please note that `*p++ = (unsigned int)v;` won't be able to set negative values. Remove the cast if you want to use negative numbers.

Comment: That's useless and error-prone, because you prevent the compiler from type-checking. Why pass `void *` if you use a specific type anyway? Very bad practice!

Comment: Actually he doesn't need to pass the address at all, since `myArray` is a global. I just wanted to illustrate as it was a `memset`.

Comment: As far as I know, it will be able to set negative values even if you don't remove the cast. But why do you need it anyway, if compiler would convert `v` to unsigned int implicitly? Also, why cast `s` to `unsigned int *`?